# change font style to Cronos in .cls file

Tags: fonts, sectioning

This is my code how could i change the font style to Cronos

```
\def\sectionfont{\bf}
\newdimen\sectionwidth
\newskip\sectionskip
\newdimen\resumewidth

\resumewidth=6.5in
\sectionskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus -.2ex % values stolen from LaTeX
\renewcommand\section{%
    \@startsection{section}{1}
    {\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{20}{20}\bfseries}% 11pt
}

\def\newsectionwidth#1{%
             \sectionwidth=#1
             \textwidth=\resumewidth
             \advance\textwidth-\sectionwidth
             \hsize=\textwidth
             \hoffset=\sectionwidth
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Your question is extremely hard to understand. What class file are you using? And please don't show code fragments, instead show a minimal compilable document using the class. This would probably only require `\documentclass{...}\begin{document}\section{A section}\end{document}`. And if the class is a custom class, you need to provide a link to it. Since the Cronos font is a commercial font, you would probably be best using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX since they can use system fonts.

Comment: Most likely your question can be solved like this: [Change section fonts](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/10139)